# javascript util.inherits issue in calling derived class functions

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have the following code where there are two functions a, c and c is inheriting from a.

```
function a(){
    console.log("constructor-a");
}

a.prototype.fun1 = function(){
    console.log("a-fun1");
}
a.prototype.fun2 = function(){
    console.log("a-fun2");
}


function c(){
    c.super_.call(this)
    console.log("constructor-c");
}

c.prototype.fun5 = function(){
    console.log("c-fun1");
}
c.prototype.fun6 = function(){
    console.log("c-fun2");
}
util.inherits(c,a);

var X = new c();
console.log("X instanceof a", X instanceof a);
console.log("X instanceof a", X instanceof c);
```

Since c is inheriting from a, the functions of both c and a should be executable from an object of C, however, in this case the outputs are as follows:

```
X.fun1() --> a-fun1
X.fun2() --> a-fun2
X.fun5() --> TypeError: X.fun5 is not a function
X.fun6() --> TypeError: X.fun6 is not a function
```

Comment: `util.inherits` needs to be called before assignments to the prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `util.inherits(c,a)` first and then create `fun5` and `fun6`.

```
function c(){
    c.super_.call(this)
    console.log("constructor-c");
}

util.inherits(c,a);

c.prototype.fun5 = function(){
    console.log("c-fun1");
}
c.prototype.fun6 = function(){
    console.log("c-fun2");
}
```

This is because of the very implementation of `util.inherits`. That function will re-assign prototype of `c` with the parent's one instead of merging. So let `util.inherits` assign `b`'s prototype to `c`'s first and then add extra functions you want.